# Maintaining absolute URLs on export with Design Manager

Tags: 2013, design-manager

We are using one 2013 *Extranet* SiteCollection as a (sort of) CDN (we can't use the ContentType HUB because of Intranet security)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://extranet.xxx/globalCSS.css" />
<script src="https://extranet.xxx/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When exporting with the **Design Manager** these absolute URLs (to the current server) are rewritten to relative URLs (I checked the .wsp package)

When importing in another Site Collection all relative URLs are rewritten again to include the absolute path to the current Site Collection.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ProjectX.xxx/globalCSS.css" />
<script src="https://ProjectX.xxx/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can absolute URLs be maintained?

TIA